# Browser Webcam Access / WebRTC - how to determine max resolution and aspect ratio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webrtc

Given the following, how do I determine the **max possible resolution** and **default aspect ratio**?

```
  openCamera: function () {
        (navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia).call(
            navigator,
            { video: true },
            function (localMediaStream) {
                if (webCamWindow) {
                    var vendorURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

                    if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) {
                        webCamWindow.mozSrcObject = localMediaStream;
                        webCamWindow.play();
                    } else {
                        webCamWindow.src = vendorURL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);
                    }
                }
                stream = localMediaStream;

            },
            function () { alert('fail') }
        );
    },
```

Comment: https://github.com/webrtcHacks/WebRTC-Camera-Resolution/blob/master/js/resolutionScan.js

Comment: @KobyDouek If this does indeed work, would you mind making an answer out of it so future readers know how to use it?

Comment: I will. It does work, I'm using it myself. I will answer it now.

Comment: @KobyDouek awesome.  To be clear - what I'm looking for is some kind of api to capture the true (not DOM-imposed) resolution and AR of the device being used.

Comment: Yes, read my answer. It scans through all possible support matrix and returns the best one it could find. Works great on my site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [webrtc-camera-resultion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43608337/browser-webcam-access-webrtc-how-to-determine-max-resolution-and-aspect-rati?noredirect=1#comment74266185_43608337) to get the best (max) dimensions and the aspect ratio of the camera.

With this library, which scans through all possible support matrix and returns the best one it could find, you can get an outcome of the camera media devices in this format:

```
label: 4K(UHD)  // Camera name
width: 3840     // Maximum width
height: 2160    // Maximum height
ratio: 16:9     // Aspect ratio
```

You can then use it in `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`:

```
{
    audio: true,
    video: {
        mandatory: {
            minWidth: _minWidth,
            minHeight: _minHeight,
            maxWidth: _maxWidth,,
            maxHeight: _maxHeight
        }
    }
}, function (stream) {
       ...
```

Comment: Do you use full scan or quick scan?  I'm testing this on my Android device and Quick Scan gets me 176x144 which is not correct.  Full scan takes too long.  Are you available for 1:1 paid assistance?

Comment: Forget paid assistance... Which android device?

Comment: Thanks Koby - this one: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B018IZ0SWI/ref=oh_aui_search_detailpage?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: Front or rear camera ?

Comment: front, testing rear now

Comment: So back full scan I get 1080x1080 and front I get 860x860, 1:1 obviously.  Is the best thing to do to just create presets for popular resolutions for quick scan?

Comment: Im using full scan while showing the user a progress bar. It takes about 2 to 3 seconds on a pc and about 4 seconds on mobile devices. Works great, didnt miss yet.

Comment: If this solution js acceptable a vote up and accepting my answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll play with it from here - this helps a lot.

Comment: Happy to help. Peace and love from israel.